# Angular 5 how to add ngx-perfect-scrollbar dynamically?

Tags: angular5, addition, perfect-scrollbar

How can I add [PerfectScrollbarComponent](https://github.com/zefoy/ngx-perfect-scrollbar) (ngx-perfect-scrollbar) selector is 'perfect-scrollbar' component dynamically to Angular 5 component?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score -1):

In your template.html

```
<perfect-scrollbar #perfectscroll>...</perfect-scrollbar>
```

In your component.ts

```
import { PerfectScrollbarComponent } from 'ngx-perfect-scrollbar';
...
@ViewChild('perfectscroll') ps: PerfectScrollbarComponent;
...
this.ps.directiveRef.scrollToBottom();
```

Comment: Ok, but how can we do that, if we have a 3th. party component for example PrimeNG DataTable? https://github.com/primefaces/primeng/blob/master/src/app/components/datatable/datatable.ts